# Draft watermark at the bottom left

Tags: draft, draftwatermark

How can I make a draft watermark like the one in this document: https://theory.cs.princeton.edu/complexity/book.pdf

Comment: Perhaps a fancy footer might work?

Comment: @TertulianoMáximoAfonso --were u able to have look at the answer

Answer (score 2):

You can experiment with the hspace for horizontal spacing -- and scalebox for magnification--color gray can be changed to red etc--

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}% http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage{url}% http://ctan.org/pkg/url
\usepackage{eso-pic}% http://ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic

\usepackage{draftwatermark}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{% Add picture to background of every page
    \AtPageLowerLeft{%
        \raisebox{3\baselineskip}
            {\makebox[\paperwidth]
                {\begin{minipage}{21cm}
                        \centering
                    Draft [Revision 269] 30-06-2012 at 07:41:41
                    \copyright\ Me, Myself and I \\
                    \url{http://127.0.0.1:9800/research/chapter1.tex}
                \end{minipage}}}}%
    \AtPageLowerLeft{%
        \hspace*{3cm}
\makebox[0pt]{%
    \scalebox{4}{%
        \rotatebox[origin=c]{0}{%
            \color[gray]{.93}\normalfont DRAFT}}}
}}




\begin{document}
    \lipsum
\end{document}
```